# Розважливий і розважатися

Tags: значення-слів

Слова "розважливий" і "розважатися" дуже схожі за звучанням, але мають протижені значення. Як так вийшло?

У словнику української мови:

РОЗВА́ЖЛИВИЙ- Здатний всебічно зважувати, обмірковувати що-небудь.
//  Який свідчить про розсудливість, сповнений розсудливості.

Розважатися - 1) Займаючись розмовами, справами і т. ін., відволікатися від чогось гнітючого, важкого, неприємного.
2) Веселитися, проводити час в якихось забавах, розвагах, потішатися чим-небудь. || Бавитися, гратися (про дітей).

Answer (score 1):

Відповідь на це питання знаходимо у значенні похідного слова в [Етимологічному словнику](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) т. 5., ст. 105
[image]

Comment: Я не знайшов відповідь у цій цитаті.

Comment: кінець цитати, яка розпочинається так: "розвиток значень проходив, очевидно, , так:...", яка підтверджує те, що ці слова мають спільне твірне "розвага"

Comment: Можливо ви могли б підсвітити, підкреслити це якось в самому рисунку в якомусь редакторі або набрати вручну після картинки?